# jQuery event doubling when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

I have been struggling with this problem all day.

I have a jQuery button that when clicked fadesIn a field. The field is a scrollable table that scrolls three times to the left and three times to the right.

The scroll length is related to its container size (overflow:hidden) however the problem I am having is that everything works fine unless I click onj the original button again. Each time this button is clicked it doubles the value of the scroll distance each direction. It is almost as if the button is doubling the event.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('.pcode_btn').click(function(event){
    var pcode=$('.pcode').val();
    var pcode=$('.pcode2').val();
    if(pcode==""){
        //nothing entered
        alert("Please enter your clients postcode");
        return;
    }

    //show calender

    $('.calender_holder').fadeIn(500);
    $('.instr').text("Select a suitable time when your client is available for one of our agents to visit by selecting an available time-slot below.");
    //slide calender

    $('.next').click(function(event){
    if($('.date_holder').css('left') != '-1743px') {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true)    
        $('.date_holder').animate({left:'-=581px'}, 500, function() {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false)    
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    $('.prev').click(function(event){
    if($('.date_holder').css('left') != '0px') {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true)   
        $('.date_holder').animate({left:'+=581px'}, 500, function() {
            $('.prev').prop('disabled', false)    
        });
    }

    return false;
});


});
```

});

Comment: Now, you struggled with this all day, and we should guess?

Comment: Post some related code and possibly a jsfiddle please, StackOverflow is not a Mind Reader.

Comment: Each time you click `.pcode_btn` - you bind another click-handler for `.next` and `.prev`

Comment: i bet there is html markup problem

Comment: the html validates - how do I stop binding another click handler should the user click the button twice ? I suppose $('pcode_btn').unbind('click'); should work to a point

Comment: @Sideshow: just move the binding code out of `.click()` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `$('.next')` and `$('.prev')` click binding handlers out of the `$('.pcode_btn')` click handler